# Populating Dealloc on my View Controller.m

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am having trouble understanding `dealloc`, release, and setting things to `nil`. I built my app thinking that I could handle memory management at the end, and am now facing serious consequences. This was admittedly a bad way to begin development of my app, but you've got to start somewhere.

Is there a guide/documentation out there that tells me what items need to be deallocated, or how to go about it? I am using `ARC`, and know that I don't need to release things, but how do I know what items need to be set to `nil` in the `dealloc` method?

My app is now pretty slow as I have a lot of methods called in `viewDidAppear`, every time the view appears it gets slower and slower. Just need a place to start. Any initial guidance would be much appreciated!

Thank you all!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906804/do-i-set-properties-to-nil-in-dealloc-when-using-arc

Comment: Also, what kind of method calls are you calling in `viewDidAppear`? I doubt your app is slowing down because of memory management since you are using ARC. You should consider using GCD to put some method calls in the background thread.

Comment: viewDidAppear is typically not a method where you do very much. If the app gets slower every time it's called, I would guess that you perhaps add new views there? You should use viewDidLoad for that kind of one-time setup.

Comment: Can you add the code for your viewDidAppear ?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1
Read this tutorial about ARC very helpfull.