# UICollectionView class reference delegate property

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I found something that I can't understand in `UICollectionView` header file. I found that the delegate has an assign property

`@property (nonatomic, assign) id <UICollectionViewDelegate> delegate;`

This question is only for my basic understanding as the rule says the delegate should have a weak property. And according to my personal knowledge, assign won't reference count the delegate object but it will surely still have a reference to a garbage value if the object is deallocated.

How can I understand this piece of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strong` and `weak` were introduced alongside [Automatic Reference Counting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) (ARC). [UIKit moved to ARC with iOS 9](https://twitter.com/steipete/status/608387828221898754), and if you look at the iOS 9 header (using Xcode 7) you will see that this property is now `weak`.

You are right: with the property as `assign` (which is equivalent to `unsafe_unretained`), if the delegate is deallocated while the collection view is alive, the collection view’s `delegate` property will point to where the deallocated object used to be and probably cause a crash when it is referenced. This is not *usually* a problem because the delegate is *often* the view controller owning the collection view so *usually* outlives the view. However, this is not a guarantee, which is why you should set `assign` delegates that point to you to `nil` in your `dealloc`.

Relevant Stack Overflow questions:

- [Objective-C ARC: strong vs retain and weak vs assign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927727/objective-c-arc-strong-vs-retain-and-weak-vs-assign)
- [Set delegates to nil under ARC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016348/set-delegates-to-nil-under-arc)
- [ARC delegate memory management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041392/arc-delegate-memory-management)

Comment: Well, I am convinced. :) That was a bit illogical to me.